# CSS-only wizard of labels with flexbox and overflow:ellipsis overflows on iPhone only

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, css-grid

I'm trying to build a **css-only (no javascript)** multi-step wizard using the checkbox-hack as described [here](https://www.mediaevent.de/tutorial/css-tabs.html). The functionality works as intended. So far so good. But, I am struggling with the formatting of my labels. What I want is:

- All labels should be of equal width, except the checked one, which should be significantly wider (flex-grow 3).
- The labels should contain both a svg(circle with number) and the label description as text, vertically centered.
- The label text should be overflow ellipsis
- The label text for the checked label should always be completely visible (no problem since the checked label is wider anyways)

I had some issues regarding the text overflow in combination with flexbox, but [this link](https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/) put me on the right track. Everything seems to work in Firefox, Chrome and Safari on my macbook, but on my iPhone the wizard always forces the layout wider and out of screen.
If I only have the text in the label, everything works fine on iPhone as well. But with the svg and the text, the layout breaks.

It's a private project and I don't have to support IE at all. But the main purpose will be to run it on **iPhones** and **iPads**, therefore it really annoys me, that it works everywhere else.

**I'd like to have help regarding:**

- vertical text align for the label text
- making this layout work on iPhone

Please check my code below.
Thank you in advance.

```css
html {
  color: #5f5f5f;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
}

.wizard figure {
  display: block;
}

.wizard>input,
.wizard figure>div {
  display: none;
}

#step1:checked~figure .step1,
#step2:checked~figure .step2,
#step3:checked~figure .step3,
#step4:checked~figure .step4 {
  display: block;
}

.wizard-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.menu-item-wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.menu-item {
  min-width: 0;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #5f5f5f;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  height: 26px;
}

.menu-item:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-item>span {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.menu-item-number {
  width: 26px;
}

.menu-item-number circle {
  fill: #5f5f5f;
}

.menu-item-number text {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
  text-anchor: middle;
  dominant-baseline: middle;
}

#step1:checked~nav label[for="step1"],
#step2:checked~nav label[for="step2"],
#step3:checked~nav label[for="step3"],
#step4:checked~nav label[for="step4"] {
  flex-grow: 3;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #A3C06C;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<main class="content">

  <form class="wizard">

    <input checked="checked" id="step1" type="radio" name="steps" />
    <input id="step2" type="radio" name="steps" />
    <input id="step3" type="radio" name="steps" />
    <input id="step4" type="radio" name="steps" />

    <nav class="wizard-menu">
      <label class="menu-item" for="step1">
                <span class="menu-item-wrapper">
                    <svg class="menu-item-number" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
                        <text x="50" y="50" font-size="50">1</text>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Label Text 1</span>
                </span>
        </label>

      <label class="menu-item" for="step2">
                <span class="menu-item-wrapper">
                    <svg class="menu-item-number" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
                        <text x="50" y="50" font-size="50">2</text>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Label Text 2</span>
                </span>
        </label>

      <label class="menu-item" for="step3">
                <span class="menu-item-wrapper">
                    <svg class="menu-item-number" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
                        <text x="50" y="50" font-size="50">3</text>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Label Text 3</span>
                </span>
        </label>

      <label class="menu-item" for="step4">
                <span class="menu-item-wrapper">
                    <svg class="menu-item-number" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
                        <text x="50" y="50" font-size="50">4</text>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Label Text 4</span>
                </span>
        </label>
    </nav>

    <figure>
      <div class="step1"> Content of step1</div>
      <div class="step2"> Content of step2</div>
      <div class="step3"> Content of step3</div>
      <div class="step4"> Content of step4</div>
    </figure>

  </form>
</main>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `min-width: 320px;` from the `body` in CSS. Or try lowering it if its absolutely needed.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't make a difference. And my iPhone has a width of 375px anyways.

Comment: @SandraMarkerud you can also add `overflow-x: hidden;` to your body as well and see if that works.

Comment: Still not working. What I really don't understand is, it works in all browsers on the laptop responsively, but just not on the phone itself

Comment: Hmm ok try one more thing,  add `overflow: hidden;` and `position: relative;` to both html and body.  like this: `html,
body {
    overflow: hidden; position: relative;
} `  and see if it works

Comment: It changed so, that no vertical scroll is possible anymore. It still overflows though.
Which means, my wizard is obviously not able to shrink enough to fit into the 375px width available on the phone.
It would shrink enough though without the svg. Maybe I still don't get flexbox in depth

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant `overflow-x: hidden;` not just oveflow, try that along with everything else from my last comment.  And also try it with removing he min-width you have in body.

Comment: No, still no luck. It would break on the notebook browsers as well now